# Selecting primary key:Why postgres prefers to do sequential scan vs index scan

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following table

```
create table log
(
    id bigint default nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass) not null
        constraint log_pkey
            primary key,
    level integer,
    category varchar(255),
    log_time timestamp,
    prefix text,
    message text
);
```

It contains like 3 million of rows.

I'm comparing the following queries:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id
        FROM log
        WHERE log_time < now() - INTERVAL '3 month'
        LIMIT 100000
```

which yields the following plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..19498.87 rows=100000 width=8)
  ->  Seq Scan on log  (cost=0.00..422740.48 rows=2168025 width=8)
        Filter: (log_time < (now() - '3 mons'::interval))
```

And the same query with ORDER BY id instruction added:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id
        FROM log
        WHERE log_time < now() - INTERVAL '3 month'
        ORDER BY id ASC
        LIMIT 100000
```

which yields

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..25694.15 rows=100000 width=8)
  ->  Index Scan using log_pkey on log  (cost=0.43..557048.28 rows=2168031 width=8)
        Filter: (log_time < (now() - '3 mons'::interval))
```

I have the following questions:

- The absence of ORDER BY instruction allows Postgres not to care about the order of rows. They may be as well delivered sorted. Why it does not use index without ORDER BY?

  - How can Postgres use index in the first place in such a query? `WHERE` clause of the query contains a non-indexed column and to fetch that column, sequential database scan will be required, but the query with `ORDER BY` doesn't indicate that.
- The Postgres manual page says:

  > For a query that requires scanning a large fraction of the table, an explicit sort is likely to be faster than using an index because it requires less disk I/O due to following a sequential access pattern

Can you please clarify this statement for me? Index is always ordered. And reading an ordered structure is always faster, it is always a sequential access (at least in terms of page scanning) than reading non-ordered data and then ordering it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can you please clarify this statement for me? Index is always ordered. And reading an ordered structure is always faster, it is always a sequential access (at least in terms of page scanning) than reading non-ordered data and then ordering it manually.

The index is read sequentially, yes, but postgres needs to follow up with a read of the rows from the table. That is, in most cases, if an index identifies 100 rows, then postgres will need to perform up to 100 random reads against the table.

Internally, the postgres planner weighs sequential and random reads differently, with random reads generally much more expensive. The settings `seq_page_cost` and `random_page_cost` determine those. There are [other settings you can view and tinker with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-query.html) if you want, though I recommend being very conservative with modifications.

Let's go back to your earlier questions:

> The absence of ORDER BY instruction allows Postgres not to care about the order of rows. They may be as well delivered sorted. Why it does not use index without ORDER BY?

The reason is the sort. As you note later, the index doesn't include the constraining column, so it doesn't make any sense to use the index. Instead, the planner is basically saying "read the whole table, figure out which rows conform to the constraint, and then return the first 100000 of them, in whatever order we find them".

The sort changes things. In that case, the planner is saying "we need to sort by this field, and we have an index which is already sorted, so read rows from the table in index order, checking against the constraint, until we have 100000 of them, and return that set".

You'll note that the cost estimates (e.g. '0.43..25694.15') are much higher for the second query -- the planner thinks that doing so many random reads from the index scan is going to cost significantly more than just reading the whole table at once with no sorting.

Hope that helps, and let me know if you have further questions.